# How to convert a CURL PUT request to Retrofit in Android?

Tags: android, curl, retrofit2

I have a cURL command

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type:text/uri-list" -d "http://localhost:8080/posts/1" http://localhost:8080/comments/4/post
```

How to convert this command to Retrofit in Android?

Comment: it looks like POST no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@PUT` annotation to handle **PUT** request in retrofit.

```
@PUT("http://localhost:8080/posts/1")
@Headers("Content-Type:text/uri-list")
Call<ResponseBody> putRequest();
```

Have a look at the official [Documentation](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)